Contribution of gravitational energy to mass of spherical shell
Suppose we have a spherical shell of mass M. Suppose we are able to variate it's radius while maintaining the same mass.
When two masses are subjected to attraction and are approached we may extract energy from the process in form of mechanical energy similarly to when approaching slowly the two opposite poles of two magnets.
So when the radius of the shell is diminished we may extract energy from the system, and the potential energy is diminished.
Given that E=mc² the mass of the system is diminished as the total energy of the system is diminished.
From electromagnetism we know that we may attribute energy to an electric or magnetic field.
We know also that inside a spherical shell there is no gravitational field generated from the shell, and the only field is outside of it as if generated by a mass concentrated at the centre of the shell.
So e.g. supposing to shrink the shell from 2m to 1m of radius, the field outside the 2m will be the same but the field between 2m and 1m meter didn't existed before shrinking, while bellow 1m the field is null in both cases.
So we may attach to that field the negative energy id est the energy lost in form of potential energy by the system during shrinking from 2m to 1m.
But if that field carries a negative energy, then it carries a negative mass and we may see it as just a hollow sphere of matter inside which there is the shell.
In that case, we may measure the gravitational mass of the shell from nearby ( just outside the shell ) by measuring gravitation. In that case the energy associated to the gravitational field outside the shell does not contribute to gravity as inside a hollow uniform sphere there is no gravity from the matter of the sphere, but if we measure the gravitational mass of the shell from far away, the negative mass of the gravitational field diminishes the mass of the shell and so a measurement of mass from far away will give as mass the mass of the shell minus the negative mass associated with the negative energy of the gravitational field.
The above are "mixed classical mechanics and E=mc²" thoughts.
Given that these problems are solved in general relativity may I have such a confirmation or counter indication ?
When we measure gravitational mass from far away or from nearby do we measure the same mass or a different mass higher when nearby ?
Let's clarify that the above reasoning supposes that the gravitational field caries energy in negative form and that energy is located where the gravitational field is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
